# Configuring WordPress Auth Cookie Expiration

Tags: plugin-development, cookies, authentication

I'm trying to configure the WordPress cookie expiration time, but for some reason it's not working. I went here:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/auth_cookie_expiration/

And put the following hook based on the doc:

```
function init() {
    // ...
    $expiration = 60;
    apply_filters( 'auth_cookie_expiration', $expiration );
}
```

This code is called from a hook in my plugin's constructor:

```
add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'init' ) );
```

And I have verified that it runs.

I expected this to produce a cookie that expires in 60 seconds, but it doesn't. Instead it sets a regular expiration time of 48 hours (WP default). I suspect this might be because when the user actually logs in, it doesn't create this expiration date, and running this function later has no effect. I haven't yet figured out how to make it work though. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you're not adding any filter callback with:

```
apply_filters( 'auth_cookie_expiration', $expiration );
```

Instead use:

```
add_filter( 'auth_cookie_expiration', $callback, 10, 3 );
```

where `$callback` is the appropriate filter callback that modifies the expiration.

Here's an example

```
add_filter( 'auth_cookie_expiration', function( $length, $user_id, $remember ) {
    return $length; // adjust this to your needs.
}, 10, 3 );
```

or to fit with your current class setup:

```
add_filter( 'auth_cookie_expiration', [ $this, 'set_auth_cookie_expiration' ], 10, 3 );
```

where `set_auth_cookie_expiration()` is the appropriate method, e.g.:

```
public function set_auth_cookie_expiration ( $length, $user_id, $remember ) 
{
    return $length; // adjust this to your needs.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I saw the second parameter being a callback in some examples, but the main doc says it's an integer ($length). Why the discrepancy? Is this version-dependent? And if the parameters in the doc are wrong, what do the other two parameters stand for? Also, how do I pass params to the callback?

Comment: I think you're just misunderstanding a little bit the apply_filters vs add_filter. We look at apply_filters() to see how to construct our callbacks in add_filter(). I updated the answer. Hope it explains it better. @Ynhockey

Answer (score -2):

```
add_filter( 'auth_cookie_expiration', 'keep_me_logged_in_for_1_year' );

function keep_me_logged_in_for_1_year( $expirein ) {
    return 31556926; // 1 year in seconds
}
```